# How to input a tab character in cmd.exe or powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd.exe

`gawk -F\t` works, but when it comes to `sort`, it fails. Under Linux or Cygwin, `$'\t'` will do it. However, to input a special key <kbd>Tab</kbd>, no way. Can anybody figure out a way?

Answer (score 3):

In PowerShell, the escape character is `` ` ``.  A string containing a tab can be written as

```
"`t"
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to fellows from Yahoo, Baidu and Stack Overflow, this tough problem is finally solved.

```
sort -t":" -k1 /var/log/accessfile
```

This statement give me a hint.

Now the answer is a combination of all tips.

1. ```
   cmd /f:off
   ```
2. ```
   sort -t"  "  -k16 foobar.txt
   ```

   (the tab character is in double quotes)

**foobar.txt** is a text file with the tab separation.

The key is the double quotes (`""`).

Comment: it's extremely easy in powershell, not tough at all

Answer (score 0):

A preferred option for me - rather than having to switch off tab-completion or change the mapped-key (to a different key) for it:-

Create a 'SetTabEV.cmd' script - to set an environment variable named "Tab" to be set to an environment variable (- consider keeping it accessible within/via your 'PATH') - you could always try the equivalent with a script for a *nix (Linux/UNIX) environment; e.g.:

```
Set Tab=
```

Run it.

Then reference/pass it's value - '%Tab%'; e.g.:

```
MyScript.cmd "A%Tab%B%Tab%C"
```

Or for PowerShell:

```
PowerShell MyScript.ps1 """"A%Tab%B%Tab%C""""
```

But for PowerShell, one-less set of quotes is possibly preferred (- triple-quoting), by using/passing the PowerShell tab escape-sequence instead:

```
PowerShell MyScript.ps1 """A`tB`tC"""
```

If you're happy to permanently have an environment variable containing a tab, you could set it via the Windows 'Advanced System Settings' 'Environment Variables', instead of using a script each time.